# Download URL for PyPi Package

Tags: python, pip

I am written a small package and have successfully uploaded the package to pypi but when i do to install using `pip`, this traceback comes and it never gets installed.

```
Downloading/unpacking pytransmit
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytransmit/
  URLs to search for versions for pytransmit:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pytransmit/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/PyTransmit/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pytransmit
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir c\temp\pip_build_dd...
No distributions at all found for pytransmit
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 270, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1157, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 285, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for pytransmit
```

How shall i make it installable using `pip`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any downloadable files for your package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyTransmit

Comment: @Bibhas Yeah, how to upload that ?

Comment: Works for me now via `pip install pytransmit` - nice work!

Comment: @DominicRodger Yes, i fixed that with `git tag` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any files to download. You can follow [the official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/distutils/packageindex.html) and upload your package files.

Essencially you need to register your package first -

```
python setup.py register
```

and then upload the distributables -

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wininst upload
```